# Packaging application with file

Tags: package, archive, pgp

I'm currently working on an application which will use the bouncy castle api in C# to encrypt/decrypt, I've got all of the public/private and pass phrase key encryption/decryption working but need to also be able to create encrypted self decrypting archives, I've read that the best way to do this is the encrypt the file using the passphrase encryption that I've written and create a light weight forms application which will decrypt the file, I've done this but my question is now how do I package the forms application with the file so that I can automatically save the file somewhere, launch the forms application passing in the file location in order for the user to specify where they want to save the decrypted file and enter their passphrase?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading many other posts I've realised that the best way to do this is by creating the application on the fly and then adding the file to be decrypted to the resources of the application.